# How to pass my own user control on the Function

Tags: wcf, function

I have a function in the WCF function. Below is the example:

Public Function testing (Byval Table as VpTable) as Boolean

Return True

End Function

My Interface:

_

Function Testing (Byval Table as VpTable) as boolean

So from the code, the VpTable actually is my own user control. This user control is basically inherit from DataTable. The VpTable just work like a DataTable actually. Just i added more some extra property and my own function inside. Question here is, how am i going to serialize it, so that WCF know what is the control is. You help is much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you having any error? As long as you declare VpTable as a serializable class (see all the rules at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/02/22/536747.aspx) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Client and Server VpTable are NOT the same type

   Even if they share the same name, the Client VpTable type will be a poor copy of the one at the server. 
   (And it HAVE TO stay this way. )
2. Only data is share between Client and Server.

   The client's VpTable won't have any method.

(server side)

```
[DataContract]

public class MyType

{

[DataMember] 

public string Foo; 

private string _bar;

public void Toto();

}
```

_bar and Toto() won't appear in the client representation of MyType.

To know why : Programming WCF Services by Juval Lowy.... very useful to understand how WCF works.